# Using NSCollectionView without bindings

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nscollectionview, nscollectionviewitem

Is there a way to use an `NSCollectionView` without bindings?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, and you don't need to subclass it.

You can use the `content` property to give the `NSCollectionView` and array of objects.  For each one of those objects, the collection view will manufacture a new `NSCollectionViewItem` by `copy`ing its `itemPrototype` and setting its `representedObject` property to the corresponding item in the `content` array.

So what I did when I did this was to create a subclass of `NSCollectionViewItem` and then overrode its `setRepresentedObject:` method to receive the new object, forward it on to `super`, and then customize the collectionViewItem appropriately.  No subclassing of `NSCollectionView` was required.  (But don't forget to implement `-copyWithZone:`!)  I simply `alloc/init`ed one of these custom collectionViewItems and set it as the collectionView's `itemPrototype`.  `NSCollectionView` did the rest.

Comment: Is there a way you could show an example of doing this? I was able to get a collection view seemingly working using bindings. My Collectionveiw item had 3 textFields and 2 chk boxes. I could output the contents of the array with log statements, but I ran into problems I couldn't solve like not being able to get the chk box state for each instance of the view item. Also the cv programming guide is not updated for xcode 4.x so I could have missed something. I would like to see an example of subclassing the item if possible

Comment: super! Moving from iOS development to OS X, it seems that binding is confusing and evil! I get terrified when things start behaving automagically